# Python script runs one day, but not the next

Tags: python, rename

I'm trying to learn Python and I've been able to create some scripts that actually work. However, one major problem I keep running into is several scripts that apparently run but immediately close again, don't do anything, and don't give an error message. I tried to add diagnostics, a check for permission, spelling mistakes anywhere, path, ran the problem through ChatGPT, checked out answers on this site, I just can't seem to find what's wrong. This is the code:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Define your starting scan and source folder
start_name = "188307_00000563"
start_date = "18830706"
source_folder = "C:\\Users\\boeo\\1883 - kopie"

# Function call
rename_scans(start_name, start_date, source_folder)

# Function definition
def rename_scans(start_name, start_date, source_folder):
    current_name = start_name
    current_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y%m%d")
    page_number = 1

    while True:
        source_path = os.path.join(source_folder, f"{current_name}.jpg")
        if not os.path.exists(source_path):
            break

        new_name = current_date.strftime("%Y%m%d") + f".{page_number:02}"
        destination_path = os.path.join(source_folder, f"{new_name}.jpg")

        try:
            os.rename(source_path, destination_path)
            print(f"Renamed '{source_path}' to '{destination_path}'")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to rename '{source_path}': {e}")

        page_number = 3 - page_number
        current_date += timedelta(weeks=1)
        current_name = current_date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

I tried to run the script, it opened a new window but immediately closed again, and didn't actually do anything. It was supposed to rename files so the correct date is in the name of the file.

Comment: Open a terminal in the script's folder, then execute the script from there so the window doesn't close.

Comment: Does the directory in `source_folder` actually exist on your system? You really should provide enough details to rule out the obvious and common beginner errors.

Comment: I copied the directory straight from Windows explorer so the name should be exact, added extra \'s based on prior advice I found.

Comment: Move the function call after the function definition

Comment: The title rembered me this [submitted bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cupsys/+bug/255161/comments/28). :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `rename_scans` method before you implement it, therefore I assume that you always run into the following exception when running it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<<file>>.py", line 1, in <module>
    fun()
NameError: name 'rename_scans' is not defined
```

You have to move the call behind the definition of the function.
Then, as suggested, starting it from the console via "python <file>.py" is more helpful because you actually will see the output of what is happening.